# Correctness of a relation for qunatum electron gas

Tags: condensed-matter

The text I'm studying in the treatment of quantum electron gas using the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation states that the following equation :
$$ \sum_{\mathbf{p},n} \frac{1}{-i \omega_n + p^2/2m-\mu +i\phi}=0$$
-where $\omega_n$s are fermionic Matsubara frequencies and $\phi$ is the zero momentum component of the bosonic auxiliary field- implies that $\phi=0$, if we assume charge neutrality in the system. But when I calculate the above summation over $n$ and put $\phi=0$ and put the result equal to zero, what I get is that the total number of particles in a non-interacting electron gas should be zero- but it's different from charge neutrality-.

So I want to know that how the aforementioned equation with taking into account the charge neutrality implies that $\phi=0$.